# Why is dispatch not running synchronously within guards on initial load?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am seeing that in some specific cases store.dispatch(...) is not executing reducers synchronously like I would have expected.  This seems to only happen in CanActivate guards and when the application is first loading.

I've put in console log statements before dispatch (A), in the reducer (B), and after dispatch (C) yet I can clearly see the output (under certain situations) get logged in the order A, C, B.  This is happening in nested guards which work something like..

- Top level guard loads entities and dispatch a LoadAll event to set entities and set a loaded flag in state to true
- Child guard gets ID from route, checks that record exists in store and selects it by dispatching a Select(id) event
- Grandchild guard uses selected entity to make some decision

In the guard:

```
console.log('A');
this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.LoadAllThings(things));
console.log('C');
```

The reducer:

```
case ThingActionTypes.LoadAll: {
  console.log('B');
  return adapter.addAll(action.payload, {
    ...state,
    loaded: true,
  });
}
```

Given the code above I'd expect console output to be A, B C.  Instead in certain situations I see A, C, B.

Can someone help explain what is happening here?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dispatch is an async action.

See https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/877

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something then.  I thought reducing state was synchronous?


https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/testing.md


So the reducer for the dispatched action is not guaranteed to have ran immediately following the dispatch?

Comment: Reducing state is synchronous, it's dispatch that isn't.

Comment: How could I reliably know that state has been reduced following a dispatch then?  My case seems pretty common no?  I have guards that need to setup and guarantee state is available for child guards.  How can I know that it is OK for the parent guard to complete and for the child guard to run?  Is there a recommended approach for this?

Comment: See https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/preloading-ngrx-store-route-guards

Comment: The approach from the article only works if you're checking if there's any data at all.  If the dispatch isn't synchronous then things become more complicated when there is data, and your route needs different data